# TextView setText from spinner

Tags: android

I have a problem with setting textView to the certian int after selecting item from spinner.
I select item from string values under than cije which is name of textview should set itself to some of variables i added before

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    String [] values =
                   {"----",
                    "Topli sendvič",
                    "Ćevapi mali",
                    "Ćevapi srednji",
                    "Ćevapi veliki",
                    "Hot dog",
                    "Hamburger",
                    "Pomfrit"};
    TextView cijena = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cijena);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(spinner.equals("Topli sendvič"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)jedkm);
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Pomfrit"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)jedkm);
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Hot dog"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)jedkm);
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Hamburger"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)jedipokm);
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Ćevapi mali"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)dvekm);
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Ćevapi srednji"))
    {
        cijena.setText(2.5 +" KM");
    }
    if(spinner.equals("Ćevapi veliki"))
    {
        cijena.setText((int)trikm);
    }

    return v;

}
```

Comment: You want an `OnItemSelectedListener`... all those .equals() will never work (a `Spinner` is never a `String`)

Comment: How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setOnItemSelectedListener` function on the `Spinner`.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // get selected item and assign to textview
        // ex: textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // handle if you'd like to
    }
});
```